# How to override version requirements from further down the dependency tree with setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I am working on a codebase with a lot of dependencies, some of which are legacy libs, that cause errors like:

`some-lib 6.0 is installed but some-lib<5.5,>=3.10 is required by {'some-other-lib'}`

I would rather deal with any version mismatch caused breakages as they come up, rather than having my code conform to hard version ranges that are only there due to shortsightedness.

Does setuptools provide a means to do so? Maybe something like "ignore-version-requirements"?

Comment: What command are you running when you get that output? Are you using pip as your build frontend? If so, are you running pip multiple times without providing a constraints file?

Comment: pip provides a `--no-deps` flag to install a package without attempting to resolve and install its dependencies. That may do the trick depending on what your approach is to dependency management

Comment: I have a setuptools setup.py file as the front end. Not pip directly, it would be too easy...